# How to hide the source code of library project in android studio?

Tags: android

I have a library project in android studio and i want to hide all the source codes of that project. I have done it in Eclipse IDE but i am not finding any ways to do it in Android Studio. Any suggestion???

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say "hide the source code"?

Comment: What do you mean by hiding source codes?

Comment: I meant hiding the java source code of the library project.
 In the Eclipse project, I had copied the project's jar file in the 'libs' folder and then deleted the java files in the 'src' folder. It is different in Android Studio so i am confused how it can be done.

Comment: I guess you mean the source code is not compiled to a jar file and it is imported "as-is" in your application?

Comment: @RanjanaDangol Have you got the solution for above question?